# Innerhtml when Ajax's result is the same as without Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, twig, xss, innerhtml

I know that use `innerhmtl` is a bad pratice (can allow XSS vulnerabilities) (https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html).

But suppose the following case :

I have a page which is generated by a Twig template `index.html.twig`.

When generating HTML from templates, Twig (https://twig.symfony.com) automatically escaping everything.

The `index.html.twig` template contains a div (#my-div). This DIV is generated by a sub-template `my-list.html.twig` :

```
  |--------------------------|
  | index.html.twig          |
  |                          |
  | <div id="my-list">       |
  |     |------------------| |
  |     | my-list.html.twig| |
  |     |                  | |
  |     |                  | |
  |     |------------------| |
  | </div>                   |
  |--------------------------|
```

When my page is called with HTTPS (without Ajax), my page is safe (because `index.html.twig` and `my-list.html.twig` are both escaped by Twig).

I want update the content of #my-div with Ajax :

- An Ajax HTTPS request is launched (same site)
- The server generates the result with the template `my-list.html.twig` (the result is as safe as without Ajax because it is generated exactly the same: escaped with Twig)
- The div is updated with `innerhtml` (with the response)

If we consider that the HTTPS request (without Ajax) is safe, why can't we consider that the request with Ajax (+ innerhtml) is not safe ? (the data is generated in the 2 same cases: Escaped by Twig).

If we consider that Ajax (+ innerhtml) is not safe, why the HTTPS request (without Ajax) is safe ?

I can remove Ajax (+ innerhtml) and only use the page in classic HTTPS (without Ajax). But the application will not be more secure. If there is an XSS vulnerability, it will be with **AND** without Ajax (+ innerhtml) (because in both cases, the template is generated the same)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `.innerHTML` is not in and of itself "bad practice"; that "cheat sheet" is tremendously oversimplified.

Comment: The combination of AJAX and `.innerHTML` on its own is not the problem. Its the fact that you cannot 100% guarantee the safety of the requested resource (MITM, DNS highjacking, modified request URL through the attacker, ...).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot for your answer. But the problems you list are not specific to Ajax. With HTTP (without Ajax), you are no less exposed to these risks.
That's why, with or without Ajax, HTTPS is important.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `innerHTML` is that people were using it for normal text which should have been encoded:

```
element.innerHTML = input;
```

or creating their own HTML without any encoding:

```
element.innerHTML = '<b>' + input + '</b>';
```

These can easily be replaced with `innerText` to get the same result, and is usually safer.

If you do specifically want to insert HTML fragments though, using `innerHTML` is correct. This then moves the responsibility of XSS safety to the code that generates the HTML.

I think you're right that if the HTML is generated safely then it makes no difference whether it's loaded by the browser on the initial page load or afterwards with AJAX.